# Visual Basic move outlook sent items to other folder

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Pro and am having a go at writing a VSTO Outlook add-in.  Essentially I want to execute code when a new item is added to the sent items folder.  I have been researching and apparently this is the most efficient way of doing this rather than having code on the ItemSend event.

I have added various MsgBox commands so I can see that various bits are actually running but for some reason the ItemAdd event does not seem to be firing.  My code is as follows:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        MsgBox("Initliasing add-in")
        AddIn_Init()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddIn_Init()
        myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items
        MsgBox("We are ready!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
        MsgBox("You sent an email from " & Item.SenderEmailAddress)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I think I am close to it working but am not quite there yet - any pointers very gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried to add Handles myOlItems.ItemAdd ?

Comment: Hi - is this not what  Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) does?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand - once I used the Visual Studio drop downs it all became clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Final code is now working - thank you!

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        MsgBox("Initliasing add-in")
        AddIn_Init()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddIn_Init()
        myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items

        MsgBox("We are ready!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(Item As Object) Handles myOlItems.ItemAdd
        MsgBox("You sent an email from " & Item.SenderEmailAddress)
    End Sub
End Class
```